# EXCEL VBA Replace last line cr+lf with lf

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user input to excel file which I need to output to txt.
It's called csv, however the delimeter isn't ";" but "|" so I need to create the file myself.

I end up with file created however I need to have each line ended with linefeed and it does the job but on the end of the created file there is an empty row with **carriege return and line feed**.

How can I stop this or delete the last line with crlf??

Functions here aren't my design I just scrapped what I found elsewhere.

Now I use this:

```
Sub CreateAfile()

rok = Format(Date, "yyyy")
Mesic = Format(Date, "mm")
dnes = Format(Date, "dd")
cesta = "\\somepath\"
plnacesta = cesta & "Data_" & rok & Mesic & dnes & "_0001" & ".csv"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim pth As String
pth = ThisWorkbook.Path
Dim fs As Object
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim a As Object
If myFileExists(plnacesta) Then
MsgBox "Existuje!"
Exit Sub
Else
End If
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile(plnacesta, True)
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Výsledek")

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = sh.UsedRange
Dim sRange As String
sRange = GetTextFromRangeText(rng)
Call a.WriteLine(sRange)
'Call a.WriteLine(sRange)
a.Close

End Sub

Function myFileExists(ByVal strPath As String) As Boolean
'Function returns true if file exists, false otherwise
If Dir(strPath) > "" Then
    myFileExists = True
Else
    myFileExists = False
End If
End Function

Function GetTextFromRangeText(ByVal poRange As Range) As String
Dim vRange As Variant
Dim sRet As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

If Not poRange Is Nothing Then

    vRange = poRange

    For i = LBound(vRange) To UBound(vRange)
        For j = LBound(vRange, 2) To UBound(vRange, 2)
            sRet = sRet & vRange(i, j)
        Next j
        sRet = sRet & vbLf
    Next i
End If

GetTextFromRangeText = sRet
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it instead of

```
Call a.WriteLine(sRange)
```

it should be

```
Call a.Write(sRange)
```

Since write doesn't add line break

Answer (score 0):

I wold suggest to add an if condition

```
For i = LBound(vRange) To UBound(vRange)
    For j = LBound(vRange, 2) To UBound(vRange, 2)
        sRet = sRet & vRange(i, j)
    Next j
    If(i<> UBound(vRange)) Then
       sRet = sRet & vbNewLine
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: That removed last empty line with cr+lf. However the last line now ends with cr+lf instead of lf.