# CSV file created with VBA has blank row(s) at the end even if cells are empty

Tags: excel, vba, csv, notepad, blank-line

I am adding some data in the first column of a worksheet and am using this code

```
Sub createCSVfile()

Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRow As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim xTxt As String
Dim xName As Variant

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1").Value = "XYZ"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A2").Value = "XYZ"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A3").Value = "XYZ"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A4").Value = "XYZ"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A5").Value = "XYZ"

Set xRg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:A5")
xName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")
Open xName For Output As #1
For Each xRow In xRg.Rows
    xStr = ""
    For Each xCell In xRow.Cells
        xStr = xStr & xCell.Value & Chr(9)
    Next
    While Right(xStr, 1) = Chr(9)
        xStr = Left(xStr, Len(xStr) - 1)
    Wend
    Print #1, xStr
Next
Close #1
If Err = 0 Then MsgBox "csv file saved"

End Sub
```

to save it as csv and delete all quotation marks based on [this tutorial](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3620-excel-save-worksheet-data-as-csv-file-with-without-double-quotes.html).

When I open the csv with Notepad there always is at least one blank line at the end:

[image]

It does not make a difference if I save the file manually - same blank line. I also tried to add something like

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Rows(6).Delete`

but it doesn't make a difference because there are no values in the 6th row of the worksheet.

Is there a way to counter this or at least automate deleting the last line in the csv via Notepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [Wolfgang Jacques](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7523634/wolfgang-jacques) suggested in the comments, I used this method instead of `SaveWorkbookAs`

```
Sub CreateAfile
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True)
    a.WriteLine("This is a test.")
    a.Close
End Sub
```

and for the last entry I used `a.Write` instead of `a.WriteLine`

Answer (score 2):

There is no blank row. You got 5 rows, each ended with a CR/LF (Carriage Return and Line Feed). The Text Editor gives you an empty 6th line.

To avoid this you would have to delete the CR/LF from the 5th row but that is not usually done.

It is fine as it is.

Comment: I am using this file for a custom software. This software does not work if a 6th line is displayed in Notepad. If I manually open it, delete the line and save it again, it works.

Comment: Maybe this takes you further? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131183/excel-vba-replace-last-line-crlf-with-lf